# Turning java application into applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I followed a tutorial for a bit of learning java 2d gaming. It included turning it into an applet. 
I use a class which is the launcher class, and it basically just launches it. It can be run as applet (using init) or an application (with main)

I expanded upon the code greatly, Adding a save and load feature using a flat .txt and .png files. which used get_property("user.home") and so forth.
Now I know that applet's on the browser can not save/view the persons computer information. So the above is useless for an applet.

What I have tried doing is commenting and adjusting *everything* that includes the persons computer information and so forth, And I still can not get the applet to load.
I am using dropbox to host it, I have tried different browsers and made sure the applet was not loaded into my cache for changes I did.

The applet in my eclipse IDE works fine-even saves, so I can't trust it, so I am using dropbox.

My applet did work, this was a long time ago before I developed the engine into my game.

I will share my GameHandler class because it holds the meat of the game. I really should organize this better. Any suggestions?
http://pastebin.com/zdmexGya GameHandler class.
I'm positive saveGame and loadGame do not even get called.

Comment: Is there an exception?

Comment: I can not figure out how to get any console or exceptions for web-browser applet.

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem now. This should help me debug it now ;)

Comment: Np, good luck.  FWIW I hate deploying applets.

Comment: The better option is probably to launch the app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). JWS works on Windows, OS X & Unix/Linux. Just like the applet it will need to be digitally signed, to read/write files on the client computer. But then, it is becoming necessary for *any* applet/JWS app. (even sand-boxed) to be digitally signed.